# javafx : How to get update value in Last Added HBox from Which is later added to VBox

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

**JavaFx get HBox Update**

I have Situation where I am Generating HBox inside For Loop and put That Hbox into Vbox outside The loop .
Now I wish to update Hbox Content with some condition ..
Like if Hbox Contain data is non overlapped it added in same last Hbox otherwise put it into new HBox ...

EX :
1,2,3,4,5,6---HBox1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,--HBox2 if(no .Starts With more than 8 like 9,10,11,12,13,14 ..I want to put it in Same HBox2 (want to update it) which added in VBox...
Is it possible..

Initially  ...,
I am Putting Final VBox Into Drag able Pane.
 if my scale from 1 to 70 
and Read File which has some numbers series like
1,2,3,4,5,6,7  ....Hbox1
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....Hbox2
2,4,5,6,7,9,10.....Hbox3......
All Series are overlapped if i got non-overlap like 12,13,14....I want to add it to Hbox3 and then add to Vbox all Hbox and put into drag able Panel....I have Problem how update Hbox content if Non overlap series got

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: yes that is  possible but but show us what have u tried? then we can help u very easly